# Restrain a protein to be helical in an MD simulation

Tags: molecular-dynamics, molecular-modeling, gromacs, proteins, protein-folding

I have a very small part of a protein that is supposed to be helical. However, in molecular dynamics simulation, it unfolds and gets into extended conformation. Is there any way I can force it to stay helical by applying any restraints, or any other biases? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the edit :-D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The general method is to constrain the CA atoms of the protein while you are equilibrating the structure. You can do this in gromacs by creating a posres.itp file that has all the CA atoms, and then having restraints turned on in the mdp file.

Comment: Thanks Hemanth. I did the same, but during the production run, after the restraints were removed, the structure was no longer alpha-helix.

Comment: You can also use a harmonic restraint to ensure that the structure remains an alpha-helix. You might need to use collars to specify that the end to end distance of the residues must remain within some distance.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on these harmonic restraints? What kind of harmonic restraints - like distance, angle?

Comment: You can use a distance restraint to keep the ends of the helix at a fixed distance, meaning that they will no longer melt away to a different structure.

Answer (score 4):

Applying restraints to keep a specific secondary structure is common/mandatory when using coarse grained force fields for MD simulations, try searching for simulations with the MARTINI force field.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Frank. But, it's an all-atom structure, not a CG one.

Comment: You should be able to use the same technique for restraining key backbone atoms in an all-atom force field.